# Allowing a user to insert/post in database just once per day everyday

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQryY.png)

i have a database that has a table name as post and inside it i have a column named as date its data type is current time stamp, so i want each of my user to login to their account and click on a task once a day, and if they have already clicked for that day the insert query will work on the database just like they have inserted a data for that day and i dont want any insert to work for that particular user again if they have already inserted/posted for that day

here are my codes av tried but not working, please help

```
$status = "";
$date = "";

// POST
if (isset($_POST['pst'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
 $status= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['status']);
 $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['date']);
```

//the date here is the old date ie the last post the user has posted maybe yesterday so am using it to check for todays date

```
 //Fetch user ID
 

  $xyttq = $_SESSION['email'];

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users where email = '$xyttq'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    // fetch the resulting rows as an array
       $pizaq = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        foreach($pizaq as $pizq){ 

       // echo ($pizq['id']); 
        $uidbq = ($pizq['id']);

 } 
    // free the $result from memory
    mysqli_free_result($result);





 // first check the database to make sure 
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date ='$date' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


// if user exists am checking the database if the user has posted for that day
    if ($user['date'] === $date) {
      array_push($errors, "Already exists");
    }
  


 // Finally INSERT user if there are no errors in the form
  else{
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO posts (userid, status) 
              VALUES('$uidbq', '$status')";
     $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);


  }
  }
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is the way that you are checking the user( $user_check_query). I think you need to use group by. You need to get all users on the same day, and you need to use the group by date. If the user doesn't exist in that query, then you can insert it into the table. If the user exists in that query, then you should give an error msg.

Comment: sir hani how do i do that please am still a baby in codes please help

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you store in your `date` column. If you store the time of post, then the time can vary and you need to check for the date range. You can check whether there are user's posts between today and tomorrow.

```
$today = strtotime('today');
$tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow');

$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS no 
    FROM posts 
    WHERE userid = $uidbq
    AND date > $today
    AND date < $tomorrow";
```

Then you retrieve `no` from the query and check whether `no` is 0 or not.

Comment: You could also use the `CURRENT_DATE` keyword in MySQL i.e `AND data > CURRENT_DATE AND date < CURRENT_DATE + 1`. Saves the trouble of having those two lines.

Comment: my problem now is i havent used this code before so please am lost on where to start it from on my codes, can u please specify where i start inputing this on my code

Comment: it is to be used instead of $user_check_query

Answer (score 0):

This table prohibits the insertion of a user more than once per calendar day:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,datetime_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
,date_created DATE NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(user_id,date_created)
);
```

Comment: tried this but it still inserting more than once a day,

Comment: It's not possible that that's true. Sorry.

Comment: or maybe please you can help with the code to back it up in my server, thanks alot